# Android and iOS Location Services

Tags: android, ios

What are differences for Location Services by Mobile Network Identified, Wifi identified and GPS identified both in iOS and Android.

Comment: Search on google!

Answer (score 0):

if compare Location Services of both android and ios mobile Network ,wifi and GPS, GPS will get location with some good accuracy and we just move mobile network or else wifi until we cant reach GPS.